# Create a renderable array for checkbox

Tags: 7, theming

I want to inject a checkbox within a preprocess function and I think it should be a renderable array.

What is the structure of a renderable array for a checkbox?

Update:

I use profile2 module and have created profile checkbox fields. While viewing profile currently the field are show as just text. I want to show it as disabled checkbox with state. So it is not within a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your render array is part of a form (outside of which a checkbox doesn't make a whole lot of sense), you would do it like this:

```
$form['checkbox'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => 'Title',
  '#default_value' => 1, // Checked by default
);
```

Have a look at the [checkbox type documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#checkbox) for all of the available properties.

**EDIT**

Just to add that `render($form['checkbox']);` also works perfectly outside of the form context using the above code; the correct checkbox element is rendered, but without the "name" and "id" attributes.

Comment: It is not within a form, I have edited the question. Please see the update.

Comment: @Junaid I've just tested it, the above works perfectly outside of the form context as well :)

Comment: Thanks. It rendered :) . I have to make it as checked and disabled also, so I have '#default_value' => 1 and '#disabled' => TRUE. But not working! It shows in enabled unchecked state.

Comment: That'll be because it's not going through the normal processing that would happen if it was part of a form :/ Off the top of my head I can't think of a way around this except to implement a theme function for that specific checkbox which checks for the `#disabled` flag and sets up the correct markup accordingly